# Stationary Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models

Ecercise 4.5 from [Bayesian Filtering & Smoothing](https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/cup_book_online_20131111.pdf) by Simo Särkkä:

> Derive the stationary Kalman filter for the Gaussian random walk
>   model. That is, compute the limiting Kalman filter gain when $k \rightarrow \infty$ and
>   write down the mean equation of the resulting constant-gain Kalman
>   filter. Plot the frequency response of the resulting time-invariant
>   filter. Which type of digital filter is it?

The Gaussian random walk model comes from Example 4.1:

$$
\begin{align}
x_k &= x_{k-1} + q_{k-1}, \qquad q_{k-1} \sim \mathcal N(0,Q)\\
y_k &= x_k + r_k, \quad\;\;\;\qquad r_{k} \sim \mathcal N(0,R)
\end{align}
$$

with $Q=R=1$.

The Kalman filter prediction and update equations for this particular case are given on page 59 (Example 4.2), or, in more general form on page 57 (Section 4.3).

Relevant posts: [How to derive the stationary Kalman filter predictor?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-to-derive-the-stationary-kalman-filter-predictor)

This left me with more questions than answers.

My understanding is that for the Kalman filter to be stationary, the filtered mean and variance should not change over time. But I don't understand how is that possible with $k \rightarrow \infty$ other than when measurements repeat themselves.

So, here am I asking:

- What is stationarity in state space models?
- Why would the Kalman gain converge to a constant with the number of observations?
- If the Kalman gain is constant, then so must be the variance P, right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the random walk model $A=H=1$.

Using this let's derive the equations (assume $Q$ and $R$ are some constants):

$$
\begin{align}
m^-_k &= A_{k-1} m_{k-1} = m_{k-1} \\
P^-_k &= A_{k-1} P_{k-1} A^T_{k-1} + Q_{k-1} = P_{k-1} + Q\\
\\
v_k &= y_k - H_k m^-_k = y_k - m^-_k\\
S_k &= H_{k} P^-_{k} H^T_{k} + R_{k} = P^-_{k} + R\\
\\
K_k &= P^-_{k} H^T_{k} S^{-1}_{k} = \frac{P^-_{k}} {P^-_{k} + R}\\
\\
m_k &= m^-_k + K_k v_k = m^-_k + \frac{P^-_{k}} {P^-_{k} + R} (y_k - m^-_k)\\
P_k &= P^-_k - K_k S_k K^T_k = P^-_k - \frac{P^-_{k}} {P^-_{k} + R} (P^-_{k} + R)  \frac{P^-_{k}} {P^-_{k} + R} = P^-_k - \frac{(P^-_{k})^2} {P^-_{k} + R}
\end{align}
$$

We can rewrite the last equation like this:

$$
\begin{align}
P_k &= P_{k-1} + Q - \frac{(P_{k-1} + Q)^2} {P_{k-1} + Q + R}
\end{align}
$$

Now we can see, that $P_k$ depends only on itself and on two constants $Q$ and $R$. At some point it converges to some constant value, let's say $P^*$.

It means

$$
\begin{align}
P^* &= P^* + Q - \frac{(P^* + Q)^2} {P^* + Q + R}
\end{align}
$$

With some elementary math we get a normal quadratic equation:

$$
\begin{align}
(P^*)^2 + Q (P^*) - Q R &= 0
\end{align}
$$

By solving this equation you get two roots, one of which is negative and does not fit the restriction for not negative covariance.

So the only solution is:

$$
\begin{align}
P^* &= \frac{-Q + \sqrt{Q^2 + 4QR}}{2}
\end{align}
$$

By substituting this into expression for $K_k$ you get some another constant value for the Kalman gain.

Here is a simple Matlab code to check the equations:

```
function [] = main()

    dt = 0.01;
    t=(0:dt:1)';

    n = numel(t);

    signal_ref = zeros(size(t));

    % system noise
    Q = 1;

    for i=2:numel(t)
        signal_ref(i) = signal_ref(i-1) + randn()*sqrt(Q); 
    end

    % measurement noise 
    R = 1;

    signal = signal_ref + randn(size(t)).*sqrt(R);

    % state
    X = 0;

    % covariance matrix
    P = 10;

    % transition matrix
    F = 1; 

    % observation matrix 
    H = 1;

    % kalman filter output through the whole time
    X_arr = zeros(n, 1);
    K_arr = zeros(n, 1);
    P_arr = zeros(n, 1);

    for i = 1:n

        y = signal(i);

        if (i == 1)
            [X] = init_kalman(y); % initialize the state using the 1st measurement
        else
            [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F); %Prediction

            [X, P, K] = update(X, P, y, R, H); %Update

            K_arr(i, :) = K;
            P_arr(i, :) = P;
        end

        X_arr(i, :) = X;

    end  

    figure;
    subplot(2,1,1);
    plot(t, signal_ref, 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on;
    plot(t, signal, 'LineWidth', 2);
    plot(t, X_arr(:, 1), 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold off;
    grid on;
    legend('Ground Truth', 'Sensor', 'Estimation');

    subplot(2,1,2);
    plot(t, K_arr, 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold on;
    plot(t, P_arr, 'LineWidth', 2);
    hold off;
    grid on;
    legend('Kalman gain', 'Covariance P');
end

function [X] = init_kalman(y)
    X = y;
end

function [X, P] = prediction(X, P, Q, F)
    X = F*X;
    P = F*P*F' + Q;
end

function [X, P, K] = update(X, P, y, R, H)
    Inn = y - H*X;
    S = H*P*H' + R;
    K = P*H'/S;

    X = X + K*Inn;
    P = P - K*H*P;
end
```

For $Q = 1$ and $R = 2$ the stationary solution looks like this:

[image: Stationary solution for the Kalman filter for different values of measurement and system noise for the random walk process]

For $Q = 1$ and $R = 1$ both Kalman gain and covariance converge to the same value:

[image: Stationary solution for Q and R equal 1]

**UPDATE**

Regarding the frequency response.

We can rewrite the equation for the state like this:

$$
\begin{align}
m_k &= m_{k-1} + K (y_k - m_{k-1}) = (1 - K)m_{k-1} + K y_k\\
\end{align}
$$

This is a discrete equation for a low pass filter (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter)). The $K$ would be the smoothing factor, which relates to the time constant and to the cut-off frequency.

I would say the frequency responce of your filter is the same as for the low pass filter and looks like this (picture taken from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Butterworth_response.svg#/media/File:Butterworth_response.svg)):

[image: Frequency response of a stationary Kalman filter]

This is my assumption, I'm not really deep in this stuff, but it seems to me plausible.

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't you have `P = P - K*S*K'` there in the `update` function?
You've plotted that to show that P and K converge, right? But, what would "plot the frequency response of the resulting time-invariant filter" mean? Does it mean that I need to use the stationary `K` to update `m` and `P`?

Comment: Also, the formula for `K_k` needs to have `S_k^{-1}`.

Comment: Not obvious to me how can I extend this to the case when I'm dealing with matrices instead of scalars.

Comment: I corrected the formula for K_k. Regarding your first comment you can have a look at formula (4.29) in the book. This expression is an alternative formula for (4.21)

Comment: I don't think it would be easy to show the same derivation in matrix form. Scalars give us a better intuition to understand the Kalman filter. I'm sure it works for matrices as well. Ecercise 4.5 deals with scalars, otherwise the R and Q matrices would have been given as identity matrices and not as scalars. Don't you think so?

Comment: I added some thoughts about the frequency response. What do you think?